# What's the best way to organize my MySQL data tables for this data?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-design

I'm working to design job estimation software for my family's home improvement business and have a bit of a conundrum about how to best organize my data.  There will, of course, be a db table for 'jobs' that stores the job name, address, description, etc.

Each job has a series of measurements associated with it that will go on to be used to generate an estimate (sent to the prospective customer) and a load-out sheet (used to determine what materials to take to the job site).

My problem is that the measurements aren't all consistent.  Here's a bit of code I put together to test the concept - notice that some measurements require multiple arrays (see: gutters & shutters), and that many items require more than the standard keys (quantity, unit_of_measure, description, price).

It's no secret that I'm no coding whiz, but I'm here to learn.  Is MySQL the wrong tool for the job here?  Do I need a different tool or should I abandon the idea of using a db for this altogether?  If MySQL is the answer, how should I organize this data?

I considered JSON stored in a db, but it seems that's poor form.

```
<?php
    $gable_soffit = array(
    'qty'=>125,
    'uom'=>'ft',
    'desc'=>"Gable Soffit",
    'price'=>6.50,
    'os'=>12,           // inches
    'ss'=>12            // inches
); 

// qty, uom, desc, price, overhang size, soffit size 
$level_soffit = array(
    'qty'=>200,
    'uom'=>'ft',
    'desc'=>"Level Soffit",
    'price'=>6.50,
    'os'=>12,           // inches
    'ss'=>12            // inches
); 

// qty, uom, price,desc
$brick_mold = array(
    'qty'=>15,
    'uom'=>feet,
    'price'=>1.50,
    'desc'=>"Brick Mold"
);

$gable_vents = array(
    'qty'=>5,
    'uom'=>ea,
    'price'=>48.00,
    'desc'=>"Gable Vents"
);

$window_tops = array(
    'qty'=>2,
    'uom'=>ea,
    'price'=>10.00,
    'desc'=>"Window Tops"
);

$openings = array(
    'qty'=>2,
    'uom'=>ea,
    'price'=>50,
    'desc'=>"Openings Capped"
);

$garage_doors = array(
    'qty'=>1,
    'uom'=>ea,
    'price'=>100,
    'desc'=>"Garage Doors Capped"
);

$porch_ceiling = array(
    'qty'=>124,
    'uom'=>sqft,
    'price'=>2.00,
    'desc'=>"Porch Ceiling"
);

$porch_beam = array(
    'qty'=>36,
    'uom'=>ft,
    'price'=>3.60,
    'desc'=>"Porch Beam"
);

$siding = array(
    'qty'=>22,
    'uom'=>sq,
    'price'=>165.00,
    'desc'=>"Siding"
);

$insulation = array(
    'qty'=>22,
    'uom'=>"sq",
    'price'=>30.00,
    'desc'=>"Insulation"
);

$shutters = array(
    array(
        'type'=>'Louvered',
        'length'=>50,
        'width'=>12,
        'color'=>'Brick Red'
    ),
    array(
        'type'=>'Louvered',
        'length'=>50,
        'width'=>12,
        'color'=>'Brick Red'
    ),
    array(
        'type'=>'Raised Panel',
        'length'=>36,
        'width'=>12,
        'color'=>'Black'
    ),
    array(
        'type'=>'Raised Panel',
        'length'=>50,
        'width'=>12,
        'color'=>'Black'
    ),
);

$gutters = array(
    array(
        'qty'=>100,
        'type'=>"5-inch",
        'uom'=>"ft",
        'desc'=>"5-inch Gutter",
        'price'=>3.00
    ),
    array(
        'qty'=>50,
        'type'=>"6-inch",
        'uom'=>"ft",
        'desc'=>"6-inch Gutter",
        'price'=>4.00
    ),
    array(
        'qty'=>10,
        'type'=>"screen",
        'uom'=>"ft",
        'desc'=>"Gutter Screen",
        'price'=>2.00
    ),
    array(
        'qty'=>5,
        'type'=>"guard",
        'uom'=>"ft",
        'desc'=>"Gutter Guard",
        'price'=>5.00
    )
);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The fun answer**: If you're up for trying something new, you could use [MongoDB](http://mongodb..org/) - it's a document-oriented database with JSON-style documents. It uses dynamic schemas which offer simplicity and power. It should fit your needs perfectly.

**The boring answer**: You can do this using MySQL, by creating a table that only consists of the most basic fields that are common for all products.

```
Products
id    name         quantity   description   price
2     Level Soffit 200        Level Soffit  6.50
5     Porch Beam   36         Porch Beam    3.60
```

Additionally, you could have a table holding your attributes.

```
Attributes
id    attribute    value
2     Os           12
2     Ss           12
5     Color        Black
5     Color        Brown
```

Comment: Thanks [Kristian Antonsen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/453331/kristian-antonsen).  I decided to heed your advice and dive into MongoDB for this project.  So far, it's great.  And you're right - it's perfectly suited for this project.  I'm at an impasse at the moment though, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620716/is-it-possible-to-define-the-key-when-inserting-into-mongodb Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to build the site in Drupal 7 with the Views 3 and the Node Relationship and Node Reference modules to do your reporting. And here is what you want to do. You create a job content type and a item content type.

The item content type will contain:

1. Your item name (the node title)
2. The description (node body, if you want to use description at all)
3. A quantity field
4. A measurement field for length, one for width, and one for depth
5. A measurement type (feet, meters, inches, etc make this a dropdown select list)
6. A price per item field (so if you have 3 doors, each 3 ft by 5 ft, priced at $2 each then it can calculate the total cost as $6 (using a custom field in views).

Then you make sure that in the job content type it has a node relationship field that can have unlimited entries of items (the content type). That way you can add whatever items you want to do the calculations. You can quickly build reports, estimates, pages, etc with views. You can even give your customer a portal to login to view estimates.

Check out Drupal.org and drupalize.me. There are a ton of great videos, articles, and resources out there for you. Also if you can think of it then someone has probably already written a module to do it and listed it for free on Drupal.org to extend your website.

Drupal will take care of the DB schema. This frees you up to do the web application buildout. Get some great designs from themeforest.net and I recommend using the Omega 960gs base theme to help get you going.

Comment: I appreciate the thoughtful reply, but no thanks.  I've used drupal for a similar project in the past and after spending and entire year and a few thousand dollars to try to bend it to my will, I decided to start from scratch and build the app with the help of codeigniter.  I'm not turning back.

Comment: You must have some pretty interesting needs for it not to work for you. We have have made it work for some very complex websites. Nonetheless, learning to build a website with CodeIgniter or another framework (Zend is very powerful too) is an experience that will help make you a great programmer. Learn to do everything the hard way and when you learn the easy way you will understand it on a level that most don't.

Comment: I went ahead an posted a second answer to give you some more ideas/help on this. I realize you have already chosen an answer, but I still like to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is the standard tool for most jobs. Actually Google uses a highly modified version of it they call BigTable that allows them to do their superfast searches. As for this project, use some join tables.

Here is what I recommend. You have these tables: project, project_items, measurement_types, item_types

The project table holds the name of the project, a project id, and any other useful project details for the overall project.

The project_items table lists all those line items you give above. It contains the following columns: item name, item description, quantity, weight, length, width, height, price, measurement_type_id (refers to the measurement_types table), item_type_id

The measurement_types table contains the name for the measurement type, a description (if you need one), the type id (auto-assigned primary key). This table is used both for categorization of data AND for determining what kind of calculations you use from the saved measurements. These calculations (formulas) can be saved in another column in this table or put into your code directly.

The item_types table has the types of items like gutters, shutters, doors, insulation, etc. You need an id column and a name column. This table is mainly used for categorization of the data.

The way you use this is to create a project to associate all the items to, then add the items to it. Each item has its measurements, name, description, quantity, type, and price. Based on which type you select you can have javascript show/hide the correct measurement fields on the entry form. Then when you do your calculations later you can use this type to know which formula to use for each item.

You can also generate some good reports using this. For price, item breakdowns, etc.