# Is it possible to define the key when inserting into mongodb

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, mongodb

Background: Using CodeIgniter with [this MongoDB library](https://github.com/alexbilbie/codeigniter-mongodb-library/tree/v2).

This is my first go-round with mongodb and I'm enjoying it thus far.  It's taken a while for me to separate myself from the sql way of thinking, but it is a perfect fit for my current project.

I'm trying to push an array into a document using...

```
$this->mongo_db->where(array('_id'=>$estimate_id))->push("measurements", $newData)->update('estimates');
```

If I encode $newData using `json_encode($newData)` I get `{"levels":[{"level_qty":12,"level_uom":"ft"}]}`

The problem is, when my function creates the `measurements` line in the mongodb document, it automatically starts an array with my insertion at [0]. Like this...

`"measurements" : [ { "levels" : [ { "level_qty" : 12, "level_uom" : "ft" } ] }]`

...leaving me with...

```
-measurements
--0
----levels
-----0
------level_qty => 2,
------level_uom => ft
```

What I really want is...

```
-measurements
--levels
---0
----level_qty => 2,
----level_uom => ft
```

I'm certain I'm missing something fairly elementary (i.e. php related & not mongodb related), but I'm an admitted amateur who has waded too deep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$push](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push) is used to append a value to an array. In your example, `measurements` is an array and Mongo is appending `$newData` as its first element. This explains the `0` index between `measurements` and `levels`. In your desired result, `measurements` is an object equivalent to `$newData` (i.e. it has a `levels` property, which in turn has an array of objects within).

Either of the following examples should accomplish what you want:

```
// if $newData is {"levels": [{"level_qty":12,"level_uom":"ft"}]}
->set("measurements", $newData)

// if $newData is [{"level_qty":12,"level_uom":"ft"}]
->set("measurements.levels", $newData)

// if $newData is {"level_qty":12,"level_uom":"ft"}
->push("measurements.levels", $newData)
```

Note: `$push` is going to be more flexible if you want to append data with future updates, whereas `$set` will naturally overwrite the given field.

Comment: Thanks, jmikola.  I appreciate the help - what a great explanation of the differences between push and set.